# PublicKey Pinning with Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have attached the .cer file for google.com and writing 2 method.
first method is on to call the URL without SSL pinning :

```
@IBAction func Request_with_No_Pinning() {
   // let sessionManager = SessionManager()

    Alamofire.request("https://google.com").response { response in
        if response.response != nil{

            print(response.response?.debugDescription as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

and it is working as expected.
second method is to call google.com with PublicKey Pinning :

```
    @IBAction func Request_with_Pinning() {
    var sessionManager = SessionManager()
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "google.com": .pinPublicKeys(
            publicKeys: ServerTrustPolicy.publicKeys(),
            validateCertificateChain: true,
            validateHost: true
        )
    ]

    sessionManager = SessionManager(

        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(
            policies: serverTrustPolicies
        )
    )


    sessionManager.request("https://google.com").response { response in

        if response.response != nil{
            print(response.response?.debugDescription as Any)
        }

    }
}
```

and it is giving me error :

> 2019-08-28 21:55:21.230911+0300 sslpinning[7184:114068] Task .<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://google.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://google.com/, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask .<1>"
>   ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
>   2019-08-28 21:55:21.232343+0300 sslpinning[7184:114069] Task .<1> finished with error - code: -999

Answer (score 0):

Your request is being cancelled because your `SessionManager` is going out of scope, being reinitialized, and automatically cancelling your requests. You need to keep your `SessionManager` around. This is typically done through a singleton.